# Partially convert non-angular-cli project to angular-cli (You have to be inside an Angular CLI project in order to use the generate command)

Tags: angular

I followed/clone this [github repo](https://github.com/linnovate/mean):

I did the: `npm install`

Then I did the: `npm start`

Project can run.

Then I want to add a new component to this project. I use: `ng generate component my-foo-component`

But I got this error:

> You have to be inside an Angular CLI project in order to use the generate command

I found some posts in stackoverflow related to my question, I tried, but with no luck. How to solve my problem. It seems like this project is not created by angular cli, so I cannot use command like: ng generate ...

I checked my package.json, I can see the angular cli as dependency?

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "angular-starter",
  "version": "6.0.0",
  "description": "An Angular Webpack Starter kit featuring Angular (Router, Http, Forms, Services, Tests, E2E, Coverage), Karma, Protractor, Jasmine, Istanbul, TypeScript, and Webpack by AngularClass",
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "angular2",
    "angular4",
    "webpack",
    "typescript"
  ],
  "author": "Patrick Stapleton <patrick@angularclass.com>",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build:aot:prod": "npm run clean:dist && npm run clean:aot && cross-env BUILD_AOT=1 npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build:aot": "npm run build:aot:prod",
    "build:dev": "npm run clean:dist && npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "build:docker": "npm run build:prod && docker build -t angular2-webpack-start:latest .",
    "build:prod": "npm run clean:dist && npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "ci:aot": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e",
    "ci:jit": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e",
    "ci:nobuild": "npm run lint && npm test && npm run e2e",
    "ci:testall": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e",
    "ci:travis": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e:travis",
    "ci": "npm run ci:testall",
    "clean:dll": "npm run rimraf -- dll",
    "clean:aot": "npm run rimraf -- compiled",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "clean": "npm cache clean --force && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist compiled dll",
    "docker": "docker",
    "docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
    "e2e:live": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor:live",
    "e2e:travis": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor:delay",
    "e2e": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor",
    "github-deploy:dev": "npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --env.githubDev",
    "github-deploy:prod": "npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --env.githubProd",
    "github-deploy": "npm run github-deploy:dev",
    "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "node": "node",
    "postinstall": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "preversion": "npm test",
    "protractor": "protractor",
    "protractor:delay": "sleep 3 && npm run protractor",
    "protractor:live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --inline --hot",
    "server:dev": "npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config config/webpack.dev.js --open --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist -c-1 --cors",
    "server:prod:ci": "http-server dist -p 3000 -c-1 --cors",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "test": "npm run lint && karma start",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
    "watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
    "watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
    "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
    "webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
    "webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update",
    "webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~4.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~4.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~4.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "~4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~4.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~4.1.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "~5.0.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~4.0.3",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.13",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.5.0",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.6.28",
    "@types/webpack": "^2.2.15",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "~3.1.2",
    "codelyzer": "~2.1.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.4",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "find-root": "^1.0.0",
    "gh-pages": "^1.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "inline-manifest-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.6.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.3",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "~2.0.3",
    "ng-router-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "ngc-webpack": "~2.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.2",
    "optimize-js-plugin": "0.0.4",
    "parse5": "^3.0.2",
    "preload-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "~2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "string-replace-loader": "~1.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.2",
    "tslib": "^1.6.1",
    "tslint": "~4.5.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.5.2",
    "typedoc": "^0.7.1",
    "typescript": "~2.2.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "~2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.4.2",
    "webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "webpack-merge": "~4.1.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/issues"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Move inside the project

Comment: @alehn96 Do you mean I create a new angular cli project, then move my current code inside this new angular cli project? But I want to fix it in my current project without creating a new angualar cli project.

Comment: If the project not is CLI, you cannot use cli generators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use `angular-cli` only for generations like

- ng g component my-new-component
- ng g directive my-new-directive
- ng g pipe my-new-pipe
- ng g service my-new-service
- ng g class my-new-class
- ng g guard my-new-guard
- ng g interface my-new-interface
- ng g enum my-new-enum
- ng g module my-module

and not actions like

- ng build
- ng serve
- etc...

you can do following:

1. be sure to be at the root of your app (where `node_modules` folder
   located)
2. run `npm install @angular/cli`, run it even if you have `angular cli` installed globally, you need this entry in your `package.json` file
3. create a file called `.angular-cli.json` with very minimal settings
   like:

   ```
   {
     "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",   
     "project": {
       "name": "angular-starter"   
     },   
     "apps": [
       {
         "root": "src",
         "index": "index.html",
         "main": "main.ts"
       }   
     ],   
     "defaults": {
       "styleExt": "css"   
     } 
   }
   ```

At this point you should be able to run

```
ng c my-new-component
```

in case you do not have ng command installed globally, you can run it as

```
node_modules/.bin/ng c my-new-component
```

make sure to explore all the available for generation options:

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-component
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-directive
- etc...
  available on or via [ANGULAR CLI git hub page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)

Comment: Your solution works. May I know where can I find the reference document about your step 2 and step 3?

Comment: I figured out these steps by examining error messages: 'You have to be inside an Angular CLI project in order to use the generate command' is caused because there is no 'angular-cli' dependency in your package.json, and another error 'Unable to find any apps in `.angular-cli.json`.' points to missing file which blueprint can be copied from https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/%40angular/cli/blueprints/ng/files/angular-cli.json

Answer (score 1):

For to Generate Component you have to go inside project folder
if you are using Visual Studio Code then

```
 Go to 
1-View
2-Integrated Terminal
or ( CTRL+` )
use the Integrated Terminal for to generate component

ng generate component my-foo-component (or)
ng g component my-foo-component
```

if you are using other Editor then 
use your command Prompt

```
Note:_
in command prompt you most be inside project folder
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that I was under a sub folder to do the 'ng generate ...', but still have that error. Will you be able to download the project and try?

Answer (score 0):

For generating component, services, or pipe inside of project you have to be inside of desired folder. For example, if you want to generate a pipe for a user component then you have to be inside of user folder.

In term of generating component use :

```
cd project
cd src/app
```

then

```
ng generate component my-foo-component
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that I was under a sub folder to do the 'ng generate ...', but still have that error. Will you be able to download the project and try?

Comment: Yea, I can try on your project

Comment: I fixed the problem after I tried the accepted answer.